# Save a simple text input form to database from custom admin controller

Tags: admin, database, extensions, adminhtml

In my extension I've created a custom adminhtml controller with a custom layout and template.

In the `indexAction` I've created a page with a simple form containing a text input. I just need to save this string to database.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You Should use your model to insert data to DB not Controller

```
$data = array('title'=>'hello there','content'=>'how are you? i am fine over here.','status'=>1);
$model = Mage::getModel('mynews/mynews')->setData($data);
try {
        $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
        echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
    } catch (Exception $e){
     echo $e->getMessage();   
}
```

or if you don't have model

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$connection->beginTransaction();

$__fields = array();
$__fields['title'] = 'The Loving Mangki';
$__fields['age'] = '19';
$connection->insert('tablename', $__fields);

$connection->commit();
```